# Problems to edit an object in react with a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, jsx

I have a component in react with a form to edit a profile user. The first render, all the info is printed, but when I'm trying to edit it, I'm having problems with a property that it's an object. If you don't modify it, and press the edit button, it update an empty field. The property that is causing issues for me is the 'address' one

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import { Form, Button, Row, Col, FormSelect } from "react-bootstrap"
import Loader from "../Loader/Loader"
import { AuthContext } from "../../contexts/auth.context"
import { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react"

import userService from "../../services/User.services"

const EditUserProfile = () => {

    const { loggedUser } = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [user, setUser] = useState()


    const navigate = useNavigate()


    useEffect(() => {
        loadUser()
    }, [])


    const loadUser = () => {
        userService
            .profile(loggedUser._id)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                setUser(data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { value, name } = e.currentTarget
        setUser({ ...user, [name]: value })
    }

    const handleAddressChange = e => {
        const { value, name } = e.currentTarget;
        setUser({ ...user, address: { ...user.address, [name]: value, } });
    }

    const handleUserSubmit = e => {

        e.preventDefault()

        userService
            .editUserById(user._id, user)
            .then(() => navigate('/perfil'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    return (
        user
            ?
            <div className="EditUserForm">
                <Row >
                    <Col lg={{ span: 8, offset: 2 }}>
                        <Form onSubmit={handleUserSubmit}>
                            </Form.Group>

                            <Row>

                                <Col>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="street">
                                        <Form.Label>Calle</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control type="text" value={user.address?.street} name="street" onChange={handleAddressChange} />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Col>
                                <Col>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="city">
                                        <Form.Label>Ciudad</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control type="text" value={user.address?.city} name="city" onChange={handleAddressChange} />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Col>
                                <Col>
                                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="country">
                                        <Form.Label>Pais</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control type="text" value={user.address?.country} name="country" onChange={handleAddressChange} />
                                    </Form.Group>
                                </Col>

                            </Row>

                         

                            <div className="d-grid">
                                <Button variant="dark" type="submit">Editar usuario</Button>
                            </div>
                        </Form>

                    </Col>


                </Row>



            </div >
            :
            <Loader />
    )
}



export default EditUserProfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You will require a state variable to track the changes in the input field. Something like below:

```
const [streetData, setStreetData] = useState(user.address?.street)
const [cityData, setCityData] = useState(user.address?.city)

const handleAddressChange = (e) => {
    const {value, name} = e.currentTarget
    setStreetData(value)
    setUser({ ...user, address: { ...user.address, [name]: value, } })
    
}

//......

<input type="text" value={streetData} name="street" onChange={handleAddressChange}/>
<input type="text" value={cityData} name="city" onChange={handleAddressChange}/>
```